# Hibernate: How to write Join queries including multi levels?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to write a HQL Query, which is similar to a MySQL Join. Below are my entities. As you can see below I am not using annotations in my Pojos. Instead I am using XML to do the mapping.

**Stock**

```
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idstock;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private Date lastUpdated;

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(Product product, int quantity) {
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Stock(Product product, int quantity, Date dateCreated, Date lastUpdated) {
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public Integer getIdstock() {
        return this.idstock;
    }

    public void setIdstock(Integer idstock) {
        this.idstock = idstock;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return this.product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return this.dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdated() {
        return this.lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

}
```

**Product**

```
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idproduct;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private SparePart sparePart;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private VehicleModel vehicleModel;
    private double unitPrice;
    private String qrcode;
    private boolean enable;
    private Integer minimumStockLevel;
    private Integer stockReorderLevel;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(SparePart sparePart, VehicleModel vehicleModel, double unitPrice, String qrcode, boolean enable) {
        this.sparePart = sparePart;
        this.vehicleModel = vehicleModel;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        this.qrcode = qrcode;
        this.enable = enable;
    }

    public Product(SparePart sparePart, VehicleModel vehicleModel, double unitPrice, String qrcode, boolean enable, Integer minimumStockLevel, Integer stockReorderLevel) {
        this.sparePart = sparePart;
        this.vehicleModel = vehicleModel;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        this.qrcode = qrcode;
        this.enable = enable;
        this.minimumStockLevel = minimumStockLevel;
        this.stockReorderLevel = stockReorderLevel;
    }

    public Integer getIdproduct() {
        return this.idproduct;
    }

    public void setIdproduct(Integer idproduct) {
        this.idproduct = idproduct;
    }

    public SparePart getSparePart() {
        return this.sparePart;
    }

    public void setSparePart(SparePart sparePart) {
        this.sparePart = sparePart;
    }

    public VehicleModel getVehicleModel() {
        return this.vehicleModel;
    }

    public void setVehicleModel(VehicleModel vehicleModel) {
        this.vehicleModel = vehicleModel;
    }

    public double getUnitPrice() {
        return this.unitPrice;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(double unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public String getQrcode() {
        return this.qrcode;
    }

    public void setQrcode(String qrcode) {
        this.qrcode = qrcode;
    }

    public boolean getEnable() {
        return this.enable;
    }

    public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
        this.enable = enable;
    }

    public Integer getMinimumStockLevel() {
        return this.minimumStockLevel;
    }

    public void setMinimumStockLevel(Integer minimumStockLevel) {
        this.minimumStockLevel = minimumStockLevel;
    }

    public Integer getStockReorderLevel() {
        return this.stockReorderLevel;
    }

    public void setStockReorderLevel(Integer stockReorderLevel) {
        this.stockReorderLevel = stockReorderLevel;
    }
}
```

**VehicleModel**

```
public class VehicleModel implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idvehicleModel;
    private String modelName;
    private String code;
    private boolean enable;

    public VehicleModel() {
    }

    public VehicleModel(String modelName, boolean enable) {
        this.modelName = modelName;
        this.enable = enable;
    }

    public Integer getIdvehicleModel() {
        return this.idvehicleModel;
    }

    public void setIdvehicleModel(Integer idvehicleModel) {
        this.idvehicleModel = idvehicleModel;
    }

    public String getModelName() {
        return this.modelName;
    }

    public void setModelName(String modelName) {
        this.modelName = modelName;
    }

    public boolean getEnable() {
        return this.enable;
    }

    public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
        this.enable = enable;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

**SparePart**

```
public class SparePart implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idsparePart;
    private String sparePartName;
    private String code;
    private boolean enable;

    public SparePart() {
    }

    public SparePart(String sparePartName, boolean enable) {
        this.sparePartName = sparePartName;
        this.enable = enable;
    }

    public Integer getIdsparePart() {
        return this.idsparePart;
    }

    public void setIdsparePart(Integer idsparePart) {
        this.idsparePart = idsparePart;
    }

    public String getSparePartName() {
        return this.sparePartName;
    }

    public void setSparePartName(String sparePartName) {
        this.sparePartName = sparePartName;
    }

    public boolean getEnable() {
        return this.enable;
    }

    public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
        this.enable = enable;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

Here are my XML mappings

**Product.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 4, 2020 1:35:36 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="beans.Product" table="product" catalog="aaa" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idproduct" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idproduct" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="sparePart" class="beans.SparePart" fetch="select">
            <column name="idspare_part" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="vehicleModel" class="beans.VehicleModel" fetch="select">
            <column name="idvehicle_model" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="unitPrice" type="double">
            <column name="unit_price" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true">
                <comment>This is the central price for a product. This can change according to the market values.</comment>
            </column>
        </property>
        <property name="qrcode" type="string">
            <column name="qrcode" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="enable" type="boolean">
            <column name="enable" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="minimumStockLevel" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="minimum_stock_level" />
        </property>
        <property name="stockReorderLevel" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="stock_reorder_level" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Stock.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 4, 2020 1:35:36 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="beans.Stock" table="stock" catalog="aaa" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idstock" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idstock" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="product" class="beans.Product" fetch="select">
            <column name="idproduct" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="quantity" type="int">
            <column name="quantity" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateCreated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="date_created" length="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpdated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="last_updated" length="0" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**SparePart.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 4, 2020 1:35:36 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="beans.SparePart" table="spare_part" catalog="aaa" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idsparePart" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idspare_part" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="sparePartName" type="string">
            <column name="spare_part_name" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="code" type="string">
            <column name="code" length="100"/>
        </property>
        <property name="enable" type="boolean">
            <column name="enable" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**VehicleModel.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 4, 2020 1:35:36 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="beans.VehicleModel" table="vehicle_model" catalog="aaa" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idvehicleModel" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idvehicle_model" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="modelName" type="string">
            <column name="model_name" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="code" type="string">
            <column name="code" length="100"/>
        </property>
        <property name="enable" type="boolean">
            <column name="enable" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Right now I have the following query.

```
public List<Stock> getAllStock(Session session) {
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Stock s");
        List<Stock> list = (List<Stock>) query.list();
        return list;
    }
```

This gives me,

1. `Stock`
2. `Product` of each `Stock`
3. `SparePart` of each `Product`
4. `VehicleModel` of each `Product`

However this is extremely slow due to the famous n+1 issue. To get data from each table, this code generated a SQL query, resulting huge amount of sql queries. The more data you have, the more queries this generates . As a result, this is a super slow process. Currently it takes 40 seconds.

Instead I need to write HQL joins and get data with a single SQL query. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't see any JPA/Hibernate mappings on the model classes.

Comment: That is because he is using XML for the mappings. No need for annotations then.

Comment: Sorry. Please show the XML we need to know how you mapped the relationships

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Sorry, I updated my question with the XML.

Comment: Ok now what do you want to do with the joined tables/entities? You only have select * from Stock

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Thank you. I re updated the question. Please check the last section.

Comment: There are many articles on that topic. I recommend https://vladmihalcea.com/n-plus-1-query-problem/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Can you provide a coding solution for this? Just take a note that in my case it is not just one join. Plus I did read many of these articles. But non of them discussa bout a case similar to me instead all about one join in one level.

Comment: The question is if you need all data from all tables or just a projection.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli not sure what you meant by projection?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli if you check the last parts of my code, I have explained exactly what I want. Normal hibernate code I have get all the data from all foriegn tables and their foriegn tables, but it is slow as it generates many queries. The solution is to form a 'join' to do the same but with one query.

Comment: IMHO it doesn't make sense to read all data at once. So the question is what data do you need?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Simon, I designed this database. I know exactly what I need. I am asking for the full data to be read because I know I need all of that data. That is my requirement. There are many places in this database that I do not need all data. In those places I don't get all data but do selectively. Here I try to get all data because I know exactly what my requirement is.

Comment: In some cases a join (see Simon's answer) is the way to go, but in other cases it is better to use lazy-load and play with the @BatchSize (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-batch). You may get away with a cheaper query followed by a small number of selects rather than N+1. You know your data best, of course.

Comment: @ewramner: Thank you for the advice, appreciate it. I am thinking of implementing some of the link's strategy in certain places of the API as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JOIN FETCH to tell JPA/Hibernate that that it should load it.

From the Hibernate docs:

> If you forget to JOIN FETCH all EAGER associations, Hibernate is going
> to issue a secondary select for each and every one of those which, in
> turn, can lead to N+1 query issues.
>
> For this reason, you should prefer LAZY associations.

```
select s from Stock s join fetch s.product p 
                      join fetch p.sparePart sp
                      join fetch p.vehicleModel v
```

Please also read the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#best-practices-fetching-associations

Comment: Amazing. Thank you Simon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use criteria implementation of hibernate and using alias you can join
Below is some reference code that may help

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Stock.class, "stock");
c.createAlias("stock.product", "product");//it is like inner join
c.createAlias("product.spare_part","spare_part");
c.createAlias("product.vehicle_model","vehicle_model");
return c.list();
```